# XPages: Sign-In Form Mapping without separate DNS entry?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I've built an XPages with an integrated $$LoginUserForm integrated in the nsf.

Unfortunately my customer doesn't want to make a specific URL for the application (the process to make local DNS entries is apparently too time-consuming to consider).

AFAIK the field 'Web Site/Virtual Server' in the form 'Sign in' Form Mapping is only going to accept either an IP Number or a URL to identify the website, so I'm stuck with using the ugly server-standard form.

Or is there a workaround?

Comment: You could use an embedded login form in an XPage in your app and HTTP POST the entered credentials using XHR to the server. A similar approach as on the OpenNTF homepage. I think there's a project on that site that you can use.

Comment: ...and there's also a Snippet using a Dojo dialog :-)
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=dojo-login-dialog-custom-control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew,

I have played quite a lot with these login forms. And I am afraid that you are right - if you want to use the builtin login redirection method you need to be able to map the login form in domcfg.nsf - either for all sites (which your client may not want) or for specific sites. I have found no way around this. Also it only works with a traditional form with the fields from the standard login form - no WebQuery-agents will run....

But you do have an alternative - if you want to control the login process yourself. Basically, you will need to test if the user is logged in (whereever that is needed) and redirect them to your own login page where you do an AJAX POST to the standard login form and read the credentials - or any login errors - and redirect to the page the user wanted. I do exactly that for an application written in XPages and Java :-)

I have defined an application viewhandler in facesconfig.xml that checks if the user is logged in - and redirects to my login page if login was required and the user had not yet logged in. To rely on Domino's security I have marked all XPages that the user can "reach" from a url as accessibly by anonymous users ($PublicAccess) and then the viewhandler checks for me - and redirects if necessary.

/John

Answer (score 0):

If there is an internet site document available (even with an IP address defined) you should be able to map your login form in the domcfg to that IP/URL and it should be displayed. Did not test it but I think I did this once and it worked.

Comment: I think this occurs only if the default internet site uses an IP address.